# Simple counting: How many bitstrings of length 6 start with 10 or end with 01?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many bitstrings of length 6 start with 10 or end with 01?

---

My attempt:

Bitstring start with $10$ is $2^4$

Bitstring end with $01$ is $2^4$

So length six should be $2^4 + 2^4 = 32$

However this is wrong so I must be missing the intersection between start and end. How do I calculate the intersection between the end and start?

Comment: Now count how many start AND end, subtract this from the total above.

Comment: @GivenPie, how did you calculate that the number of bitstrings that start with 10 is $2^4$? Is there a principle that applies to the intersection?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal You mean since the start and end are $10$ and $01$, then there are 4 bits. Therefore I must subtract 4 from 32. Bringing the total amount of string to $32-4=28$, correct?

Comment: Yea, since the end and beginning are already determined, there are only 2 spots left so 4 different possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^2 = 4$ bitstrings of length $6$ that starts with $10$ and ends with $01$. So taken into consideration of your analysis, the answer is: $32 - 4 = 28$. The reason we remove $4$ is that there are $4$ bitstrings length $6$ that satisfy both conditions (other than the first and last 2 bits, there are 2 bits not defined and therefore $2^2=4$ possibilities)